# C - Improving (really) big number addition

Tags: c

I was lucky enough to stumble into this task during a job interview.  I was gently guided to use string reversals and a few other things to speed up my process.  I kept thinking that I wouldn't have done it the way I was coached.   It bothered me enough that I went home and coded up my version.

How could I improve this code?

*** EDIT *** added a size_t for carry.  Reduced the number of calles of strlen().

Rules:

- Program must be in C
- Can't use atoi, and only basic types
- Must be able to add arbitrarily large numbers
- Output must be a string

Example usage:

```
addbig 12345678901234567891234567891234567890123456789123456789  9876543210987654321098765432198765432109876543210987654321
```

Here's the code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc
#include <string.h>  // strlen


char * addStrings(char* string1, char* string2) {
  char *maxString = string1;
  char *minString = string2;

  // Override our larger if we were wrong.
  if (strlen(string1) < strlen(string2)) {
    maxString = string2;
    minString = string1;
  }

  int maxSize =  strlen(maxString);

  // Allocate enough storage to include our carry and the null char at the end.
  char * myResult = malloc(maxSize + 2);

  // Null terminate the string
  myResult[maxSize + 1] = 0;

  size_t carry = 0;
  int mindex = strlen(minString) - 1;

  char x = 0;

  // One loop.  Avoid -std=c99 flag
  int i = maxSize - 1;
  for (; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Default our char
    x = maxString[i] - '0';
    // We still have something left to add.
    if (mindex >= 0){
      x = x + (minString[mindex] - '0');
      mindex--;
    } 

    if (carry) x++;

    if (x >= 10) {
      x -= 10;
      carry = 1;
    } else {
      carry = 0;
    }

    myResult[i + 1] = x + '0';
  }
  // Take care of any leftover carry.
  if (carry) myResult[0] = '1';

  return myResult;
}  // END addStrings()



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s num1 num2\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Utility for big numbers.");
    printf("Adds num1 to num2, for any length of numbers.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char * result = addStrings(argv[1], argv[2]);

  // Removing the initial space allocated by storage if we didn't overflow
  printf("%s\n", (result[0] == ' ') ? result + 1 : result);

  if (result) {
    free(result);
    return 0;
  }

  // Returned an error state, memory not freed.
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: You only need 2 `strlen` calls, not 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Function Error**

1. What is `myResult[0]` when `carry == 0`?

   ```
   if (carry) myResult[0] = '1';
   ```

**Improvements**

1. As code is not changing the the contents of the string, use `const` for potential compiler optimization and clarity to reviewers that code is in fact not changing the characters.

   ```
   // char * addStrings(char* string1, char* string2) 
   char * addStrings(const char* string1, const char* string2)
   ```
2. Code that allocates memory should clearly say that as a comment and/or function name.

   ```
   // Returns an allocated string representing the sum of .... 
   char * addStrings(
   // or
   char * addStrings_alloc(
   ```
3. *Really* big strings can exceed length `INT_MAX`.  Use `size_t` for indexing arrays and string lengths.  `size_t` *is* the return type of `strlen()`.

   ```
   // int maxSize =  strlen(maxString);
   size_t maxSize =  strlen(maxString);

   // int i = maxSize - 1;
   // for (; i >= 0; i--) {
   size_t i;
   for (i = maxSize; i > 0; ) {
     i--;
   ```
4. Check the return value of `malloc()`

   ```
   char * myResult = malloc(maxSize + 2);
   if (myResult == NULL) return NULL;
   ```
5. No need for `carry to be`size_t`.

   ```
   // size_t carry = 0;
   int carry = 0;
   ```
6. No provision for `-` numbers. (or ones with a leading `'+'`)
7. No provision for trimming leads `'0'` in answer with input like `addStrings("007", "007")`
8. No provision for non-digits as in `addStrings("x", "007")`
9. Simplification

   ```
      // x = maxString[i] - '0';
      // if (carry) x++;
      x = maxString[i] - '0' + carry;
   ```
10. Below processing should have happened in the function.

    ```
      // Removing the initial space allocated by storage if we didn't overflow
      ... (result[0] == ' ') ? result + 1 : result)
    ```

**Minor**

1. Nomenclature.  *size* is the size need for the array.  *length* is the length of the string (not counting the null character).  Suggest `maxLength`.

   ```
   // int maxSize =  strlen(maxString);
   int maxLength =  strlen(maxString);
   ```
2. Why the comment? Seems unneeded  `// Avoid -std=c99 flag`
3. No provision for `NULL` input  `addStrings(NULL, "007")` - but then `NULL` is not a valid string.  For an interview question, I'd at least suggest that inputs may need sanitizing before use.
4. Style: Even single `if()` are easier to debug/maintain with `{}`

   ```
   // if (carry) myResult[0] = '1';
   if (carry)  {
     myResult[0] = '1';
   }
   ```
5. Test driver simplification.  `free(NULL)` is OK.

   ```
   // if (result) {
   //  free(result);
   //  return 0;
   //}
   free(result);
   ```
6. Test driver function error - off by 1

   ```
   // if (argc < 2) {
   if (argc < 3) {
   // or better 
   if (argc != 3) {
   ```
7. I'd expect code to be tested and give a reasonable (or a least defined) result with `addStrings("", "7")` and `addStrings("", "")`

Comment: Seriously great response!  #1 was a bug I introduced late last night after I core dumped freeing the memory allocated in the function.  Apparently the pointer arithmetic loses the malloc accounting details, which is why #10 is that way.  Why did you structure the size_t for loop that way?

Comment: @MrMowgli  `size_t` is some unsigned type.  `size_t i = maxSize - 1;
  for (; i >= 0; i--) {` is always true - infinite loop.

Comment: Got it.  But why break out the i--?

Comment: @MrMowgli  The `i--` is just the first statement in the `for` loop.  Could use `for (i = maxSize; i-- > 0; ) { ... }`  6.00001 or half-a-dozen of the other.  It is a style issue.

Comment: Rather why not --i in the loop?

Comment: Just saw your comment.  Looks good.  I'm going to accept this as the answer, but I'm still curious what other optimizations might pop up.  Also how to deal with freeing the memory allocation from returning an offset pointer without allocating again?

Comment: @MrMowgli `for (i = maxSize; --i > 0; ) {` is an infinite loop. `for (i = maxSize; i > 0; --i) {` decrements too late

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39701/discussion-between-chux-and-mrmowgli).

Answer (score 0):

Malloc allocates uninitialized memory. You need to `memset` it unless you enjoy dealing with undefined behavior.

```
char * myResult = malloc(maxSize + 2);
memset(myResult, 0, maxSize + 2);
```

Comment: Aside from bug noted [Function Error #1](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/128185/29485) the `memset()` is not needed.  When zero filling is needed, simple to use `calloc()`.

Comment: No need to. All the requested memory is initialized later anyway.